# How can i label input and output ports of my QuantumCircuit in qiskit?

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, quantum-circuit

I made quantum circuits as quantum gates then later used these gates in a larger circuit. Here, the input ports of the block (which is the gate) are labelled by integers but i want to custom label input and output ports of the block, to show how the states change and to remember where to get the value of specific qubit.

Like in the picture input ports are 0,1,2..7 i want to label them m0, m1,..m7 and similarly, k7,k3,..k0 for the output port.

[image]